# Make a new variable, var3, by taking the count of all values of var1 and dividing by unique values of var1, over unique values of var2

Tags: python, r, pandas, group-by

I'm trying to plot the average number of clicks on a given day over a one week period. The data i'm working with can be [found here](https://github.com/wikimedia-research/Discovery-Hiring-Analyst-2016/blob/master/events_log.csv.gz) if you want to take a look. But briefly, it is structured as so:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 400165 entries, 0 to 400164
Data columns (total 9 columns):
uuid               400165 non-null object
timestamp          400165 non-null object
session_id         400165 non-null object
group              400165 non-null object
action             400165 non-null object
checkin            223824 non-null float64
page_id            400165 non-null object
n_results          136234 non-null float64
result_position    230482 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3), object(6)
memory usage: 27.5+ MB
```

And the output of `df.head()` looks like:

```
    uuid    timestamp   session_id  group   action  checkin page_id n_results   result_position
0   00000736167c507e8ec225bd9e71f9e5    20160301103842  78245c2c3fba013a    b   searchResultPage    NaN cbeb66d1bc1f1bc2    5.0 NaN
1   00000c69fe345268935463abbfa5d5b3    20160307005226  c559c3be98dca8a4    a   searchResultPage    NaN eb658e8722aad674    10.0    NaN
2   00003bfdab715ee59077a3670331b787    20160302145305  760bf89817ce4b08    a   checkin 30.0    f99a9fc1f7fdd21e    NaN NaN
3   0000465cd7c35ad2bdeafec953e08c1a    20160302222701  fb905603d31b2071    a   checkin 60.0    e5626962a6939a75    NaN 10.0
4   000050cbb4ef5b42b16c4d2cf69e6358    20160302095023  c2bf5e5172a892dc    a   checkin 30.0    787dd6a4c371cbf9    NaN NaN
```

There are 8 unique values of `df['date']` and I want to make a new variable that equals (the count of all values of `sessionid` on a given date) divided by (the count of unique values of `sessionid` on that same date).

I'd love to do this in one step, but i think i've managed to get part of the way there with this code:

```
df['sessions_bydate'] = df.groupby('date')['session_id'].nunique().sum()
pd.crosstab(df['date'], df['sessions_bydate'])

#Which produces this output:

test2   68110
date    
2016-03-01  59324
2016-03-02  60322
2016-03-03  60643
2016-03-04  45745
2016-03-05  36242
2016-03-06  41199
2016-03-07  52557
2016-03-08  44129
```

Interestingly though, this looks like the count of all values of `sessionid` by date, not the count of all unique values, even though i'm using `nunique()`. Not sure what i'm doing wrong there.

Ultimately, my objective is to produce a line plot with lowess estimation that shows the average number of clicks per session per date. If i'm approaching it in a strange way, let me know. I'm very open to alternatives.

If helpful, in R, what i'd want to do is:

```
# Data transformation
CTR <- df %>%
            group_by(date) %>%
            summarise("click_through_rate" = n()/
                        n_distinct(session_id))
# Graphical representation
ggplot(CTR, aes(x = date, y = click_through_rate)) + 
  geom_step() +
  ylim(c(0,NA)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  labs(title = "Daily click-through rate")
```

**EDIT:**
At the suggestion of one of the comments, i include here a small snippet of data that should have the right structure needed to replicate my problem (obtained using `df1.head(18).to_dict()`). I've manually made this snippet in excel, and the variables `all_values` and `unique_values` are not in my actual data. I think I want to create them in order to make what I actually want: `all_values \ unique_values`. But if there's a way to skip straight to the finish line, i'm all ears

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'all values': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 4, 7: 3, 8: 3, 9: 3, 10: 3, 11: 3, 12: 3, 13: 5, 14: 5, 15: 5, 16: 5, 17: 5},
    'sessionid': {0: '000936ae06d62383', 1: '000936ae06d62383', 2: '0024f4f005f34c9d', 3: '002601319d1a02e1', 4: '0029420a5f8c7d90', 5: '002601319d1a02e1', 6: '002601319d1a02e1', 7: '002ad4609eedc350', 8: '002ad4609eedc350', 9: '002ad4609eedc350', 10: '002b97995ca9ce77', 11: '002b97995ca9ce77', 12: '002ad4609eedc350', 13: '003f93d4791463c9', 14: '003f93d4791463c9', 15: '00429c6a475ab250', 16: '002b97995ca9ce77', 17: '00429c6a475ab250'},
    'unique_values': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 2, 11: 2, 12: 2, 13: 3, 14: 3, 15: 3, 16: 3, 17: 3},
    '\ufeffdate': {0: '02/01/2016', 1: '02/01/2016', 2: '02/01/2016', 3: '03/01/2016', 4: '03/01/2016', 5: '03/01/2016', 6: '03/01/2016', 7: '04/01/2016', 8: '04/01/2016', 9: '04/01/2016', 10: '05/01/2016', 11: '05/01/2016', 12: '05/01/2016', 13: '06/01/2016', 14: '06/01/2016', 15: '06/01/2016', 16: '06/01/2016', 17: '06/01/2016'}
    })
```

Comment: Welcome! Yours is a very well structured question. See how to provide pandas df samples here https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/6692898

Comment: Thanks! I've just added something using `df1.head(18).to_dict()`. Hope that works

Comment: your sample seems to be already aggregated... what does `unique_values` mean in that df? Can you provide a similar sample but before applying groupby?

Comment: `unique_values` and `all values` are variables i want to create. Ultimately I want a variable of `all_values / unique_values`. I've clarified this in the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your statement correctly.  It's a simple `lambda` function in `agg()`

```
# df = pd.read_csv("events_log.csv")
df1 = df.loc[:]
df1 = df1.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df1.loc[:,"timestamp"].astype(np.int64), 
                                     format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S").dt.floor("D"))
dfr = df1.groupby("date").agg({"session_id":lambda s: s.count()/len(s.unique())})
print(dfr.to_string())
```

**output**

```
            session_id
date                  
2016-03-01    6.406479
2016-03-02    6.546066
2016-03-03    6.480445
2016-03-04    5.542954
2016-03-05    5.377151
2016-03-06    5.388438
2016-03-07    5.506338
2016-03-08    5.452063
```

Comment: Hi Rob, that's exactly what I was after. Thank you! I'd upvote your answer but I don't have enough points to do that (sorry). Do you know how I could then go about turning these data points into a line graph, with date on the xaxis and the numbers you produced on the yaxis?

Comment: I must admit I don't do much plotting.... `%matplotlib inline
ax = dfr.plot()` in my jupyter notebook does then generate graph you want.  Not beautified!    Accept my answer and I'll get more rep points :)

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot Rob. I tried to upvote your answer but I don't have a high enough 'reputation score'. I accepted your answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

Working with your original data source. First group by date and session_id:

```
#with gzip.open(pth+'events_log.csv.gz', 'rb') as fo:
#    df = pd.read_csv(fo)
#df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp.astype(np.int64), format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

by_date_id = (
    df.groupby([df.timestamp.dt.date, 'session_id']).uuid.size()
    .rename('rowct').to_frame()
    )
```

Output:

```
                             rowct
timestamp  session_id
2016-03-01 000936ae06d62383      1
           001544bc03fac3e8      2
           001a3950cd4ac6c6      5
           001e2d0e159172d2      3
           0022bba0634595b9      1
...                            ...
2016-03-08 ffdf5d155e9b5c19     20
           ffdfd6a8ffbbee8a      1
           ffe1a14d4565573d     17
           fffa387663722d38      1
           fffac2c4111308d0      1
```

Now to summarize by date:

```
by_date = by_date_id.groupby('timestamp').agg(['sum', 'size'])
by_date.columns = ['rowct', 'unique_sessions']
```

Output

```
            rowct  unique_sessions
timestamp
2016-03-01  59324             9260
2016-03-02  60322             9215
2016-03-03  60644             9358
2016-03-04  45746             8253
2016-03-05  36242             6740
2016-03-06  41200             7646
2016-03-07  52558             9545
2016-03-08  44129             8094
```

From here on you can divide `by_date.rowct / by_date.unique_sesssions`

Comment: Richie, this is an elegant solution. Thanks a lot! And I appreciate your pointers on how best to share data on SO.